# Django South Migration To Access Flatpages App

Tags: django, django-south, django-flatpages

I am trying to access the Flatpages models in a South migration like so:

```
s = orm['flatpages.Site'].objects.get(id=10)
f = orm['flatpages.FlatPage'].objects.get(id=10)
```

I get errors saying that site and flatpage models are not available in the flatpages app.  So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you run syncdb after including flatpages in `installed_apps`?

Comment: yes several times it did not help

Comment: and did you add the url patterns too ?

Comment: the flatpages app itself is working fine  it is the migration where I am having the issue

Comment: does `./manage.py sql flatpages` show the sql for `Site` and `FlatPage`? Can you import the models into the shell console and create them?

Comment: I have not tried the manage sql flatpages command but I have imported FlatPages and Site in the shell and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it via South's `orm` object, but you can break the recommendation and import the model directly if you're simply looking to force a data migration, e.g.,

```
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
        f = FlatPage.objects.create(
            title="Page Name",
            url="/url/",
            content="..."
        )
        f.sites.add(site)
        f.save()
```

Comment: This is the way I ended up doing it but it is frowned upon according to the South docs and comments that are generated in the migration.